# Pip within Pyenv-virtualenv installing into system on Big Sur

Tags: pip, pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

I have installed and been using [Pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) for some time now, utilizing the [Pyenv Virtualenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv) plugin to create `venv`s and activating automatically by including a `.python-version` as per the plugin [docs](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv#activate-virtualenv).

It seems to not always work as expected, though. Recently upgraded OSX to Big Sur.

Pip seems to be installing packages globally, rather than into the `venv`:

```
pyenv versions
  system
  2.7.17
  3.8.5
  3.9.5
* 3.9.5/envs/project_venv (set by /Volumes/path_to_my_project/.python-version)
  fulfill
```

So far, so good.

```
pyenv which pip
/Users/mikekilmer/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/envs/project_venv/bin/pip
```

As I would expect.

Here's where I'm confounded:

Outside of the `venv`:

```
$ pyenv which pip
/Users/mikekilmer/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/bin/pip
$ pip list -v
Package           Version   Location                                                      Installer
----------------- --------- ------------------------------------------------------------- ---------
# all the global pip packages...
defusedxml        0.7.1     /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages                        pip
# No Django, which is good
idna              2.10      /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages                        pip
```

Inside of the `venv`:

```
$ pip install django
# installation output...
$ pip list -v
# abridged
Django            3.2.5     /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages                        pip
## That's not supposed to be in the global packages!!!
```

And of course Django is also in the global `pip list`.

## But wait...

Look at this:

```
$ /Users/mikekilmer/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/envs/project_venv/bin/pip install django
# installation output...
$ /Users/mikekilmer/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/envs/project_venv/bin/pip list -v
asgiref    3.4.1   /Users/mikekilmer/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/envs/project_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
Django     3.2.5   /Users/mikekilmer/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/envs/project_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
pip        21.1.1  /Users/mikekilmer/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/envs/project_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
pytz       2021.1  /Users/mikekilmer/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/envs/project_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
setuptools 56.0.0  /Users/mikekilmer/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/envs/project_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
sqlparse   0.4.1   /Users/mikekilmer/.pyenv/versions/3.9.5/envs/project_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
```

Now it's installed to the correct place.

But that's not the way it's supposed to work, is it? It seems that somehow, `pyenv` *thinks* that it's using the `venv` pip, but isn't.

When I run `which pyenv`, it returns this function:

```
pyenv () {
    local command
    command="${1:-}"
    if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]
    then
        shift
    fi
    case "$command" in
        (activate | deactivate | rehash | shell) eval "$(pyenv "sh-$command" "$@")" ;;
        (*) command pyenv "$command" "$@" ;;
    esac
}
```

I am not finding that code in the [pyenv repository](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/search?q=local+command) and I'm using the latest master (`pyenv 2.0.3`) via Homebrew.

Any insights?

### Update

Seems that `pip` is symlinked to `/usr/local/bin/pip3`:

```
$ which pip
pip: aliased to /usr/local/bin/pip3
```

While `pip3` points correctly to the `pyenv` location:

```
$ which pip3
/Users/mikekilmer/.pyenv/shims/pip3
```

`$PATH` starts like this:

```
/var/folders/62/38l28z6j12s9lqp6nnhmrlhc0000gn/T//zsh-501/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/pyenv-virtualenv/1.1.5/shims:/Users/mikekilmer/.pyenv/shims:/Users/mikekilmer/.pyenv/bin
```

The first directory is empty and [seems to be](https://www.swiftforensics.com/2017/04/the-mystery-of-varfolders-on-osx.html) part of the Darwin cache directory:

```
$ getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR
/var/folders/62/38l28z6j12s9lqp6nnhmrlhc0000gn/C/
```

I'm not sure how it got appended to my `PATH` (by `zsh`?) or if it could somehow be making the shell think it should find `pip` elsewhere than with `pyenv`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was similarly confused at some point. Turned out that I installed / upgraded  python and pip with different methods (brew, easy_install, curl, sudo ...). That's why my paths got messed up.

---

Removing pip everywhere and reinstalling it helped.

*When I run `which pyenv`, it returns this function:*

```
pyenv () {
    local command
    command="${1:-}"
    if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]
    then
        shift
    fi
    case "$command" in
        (activate | deactivate | rehash | shell) eval "$(pyenv "sh-$command" "$@")" ;;
        (*) command pyenv "$command" "$@" ;;
    esac
}
```

You can add pyenv to the PATH in your ~/.zshrc or ~/.zshenv in order to get the correct path.

```sh
echo 'export PATH=$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.zshenv
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope for a more complete explanation, but installing with `pip3` solved the issue.